# I need to match a URL with a forward slash, but skip the first match

Tags: regex

I am new to regex so this may be easy.

(UPDATED description)
I need a regex to skip the first occurrence of a the forward slash in a URL, but match the string on all subsequent occurrences of the forward slash.

When it matches, the string to return is should be the entire URL without the last slash.

For example:
rootURL   is skipped
rootURL/  is skipped

rootURL/abc/   is matched. This would return rootURL/abc   (without the last forward slash)

rootURL/abc/123/ is matched. This would return rootURL/abc/123   (without the last forward slash)

rootURL/abc/456 is NOT matched.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code you already having so far?

Comment: This is the expression that I have so far:  ^(.*)/    This does everything I want except it matches on the first forward slash, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression is just simply `.*/.*/.*`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match more than one slash you can use this regex:

```
\w+/(?:\w+/)+
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/oK8xL9/1)**

[image]

Comment: I updated my description of the problem.  This seems to be close but I need it to return the string without the last forward slash.  See my updated examples.  Thanks!

Comment: @craigAllens fixed, you can check this link http://regex101.com/r/oK8xL9/2 with the working solution

Comment: I tested this solution and it matches correctly, but the returned string that is returned should NOT have the last forward slash on it.  So when aa/bb/ is matched, it should return aa/bb  (no ending slash).  Let me know if you have any ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: This is working better, but when testing, I noticed it doesn't work for the following URL that I need it to work for:   http://server:8080/path/codes/   Do you think you could make it work for this situation?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`^rootURL/(.+)$`
The end marker after the dot force at least one char to be here.

Answer (score 0):

```
.*?\/(.*$)
```

This works.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/30